# JVM - How is non jit-compiled code run

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I know that some piececes of the bytecode are compiled into assembly at runtime. However all resources that I read do not mention what happens to the rest of the code. Is it interpreted by c++?

Comment: You are mixing up terms. Some byte code is compiled to *native code*, no assembly step involved. The byte code which is not compiled will get interpreted; the interpreter *might* be implemented using C++, but whether it is, is irrelevant as at runtime, the interpreter will consist of executable native code, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JIT compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiles the byte-code to native code for execution; if you're on a platform without a JIT then the byte-code is interpreted.